# How to show only the active desktop's applications in the taskbar? (Lubuntu 18.10)

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, window-manager, panel, 18.10

The default setting is to show all open applications in the taskbar regardless of active desktop. I wish to show only the windows in the active desktop in that desktop's taskbar. How do I show only the active desktop's applications in the taskbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the taskbar, click 'Configure "Task manager"', and enable "Show only windows from desktop 'Current'".

(courtesy of marneu in #lubuntu)